# No module named import_export although it is in site-packages

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am beginner in Django and I am using this by installing with pip on my server.

https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export

My python version is 2.7.

This is m **PYTHONPATH**,

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7:/home/khantthulinn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This is my sys.path.

```
/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg
/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7
/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7
/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/myproject
/usr/lib64/python27.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/khantthulinn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/geos
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I really saw **import_export** here like this.

[image]

But when I import in my **settings.py** like this, it say no module named **import_export**.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'provider',
    'provider.oauth2',
    'push_notifications',
    'import_export',
)
```

How shall I do?

Comment: Try print `sys.path` just before `INSTALLED_APPS`. Maybe Django doesn't pick up values from your PythonPath?

Comment: I just try now. I saw my pythonpath when i print just before INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: What about `import_export` module in site-packages/ ? What `pip freeze` shows? `.dist-info` should contains metadata only if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I have problem with pip freeze. I have multiple python and I am not sure whether which python pip is using. And yes .dist-info is only metadata. But I install that from pip too. Why is it only metadata? How can I install properly?